# AKAudioPlayer looping doesn'work

Tags: audiokit

I'm using AudioKit 4.01 on iOS.
After using AKAudioPlayer.replace(file:), the AKAudioPlayer doesn't loop anymore correctly : it doesn't take the value "endTime" into account anymore, the file plays until the end. Is that a bug or something I missed?

Comment: Please add your code to the question. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You say that AudioKit doesn't take into account `endTime` any more after you replace the file. `AKAudioPlayer` resets its `endTime` when `reloadFile()` or `replace(file:)` is called.

Call hierarchy as of 4.0.1 :

`replace(file:)` -> `reloadFile()` -> `initialize()`

`initialize()` sets `endingFrame = totalFrameCount`, which is what `endTime` is calculated from.

Solution is to set the `endTime` again after `replace(file:)`